# There are $2n+1$ statements. In maths, a statement is defined as a sentence that is either true or false.

Tags: probability

> There are $2n+1$ statements. In maths, a statement is defined as a sentence that is either true or false. It is known that $n$ of these statements are true, whereas the result of $n+1$ statements is unknown. A statement is picked at random. If the probability that the statement picked is true, is $31/42$, then n is equal to:

My Approach:

I am not able to find how many statements are correct out of unknown statements?
Let $x$ be the true statements out of unknown $n + 1$ statements.
So, the total number of true statements equals $x + n$
$31/42 = x+nC1/2n+1C1$.

On solving, $x = (62n+31)/42$. However, I am not able to find out $n$ with this approach.

Comment: Please don't put half your question in the title and the other half in the body.  Titles are for searching and summarizing.

Comment: How did you get $x=(62n+31)/42$? When I solve $31/42=(x+n)/(2n+1)$ I get $x=(20n+31)/42$. Either way, $x$ can't be an integer, because $42x$ is equal to an odd number.

Comment: You mention in the title that there are $2n+1$ statements in all, but you do not directly include this assumption in the body of your Question.  The Question should have a self-contained problem statement.

Answer (score 4):

If $k$ (with $0\le k\le n+1$) of the $n+1$ "unknown" statements are actually true, then the probability of picking a true statement is $\frac{n+k}{2n+1}$. So here we are told that $\frac{n+k}{2n+1}=\frac{31}{42}$. However, the fraction on the left has an odd denominator, and even if it is not in shortest terms yet, the denominators will remain odd after cancelling any common factors. Hence it certainly cannot be a fraction with denominator $42$ in shortest terms.

Answer (score 1):

> whereas the result of $n+1$ statements is unknown

If the number of true statements among these is fixed, then there is no solution.

However, if the truth value of these statements is taken to be random with probability $\tfrac{1}{2}$ for each value, then we are tasked with solving

$$\frac{n+\tfrac{n+1}{2}}{2n+1}=\frac{31}{42}\text{.}$$